# Sorting small arrays multiple times

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array-algorithms

I'm trying to sort small array like

```
var arr=[{x:1,y:2,z:1},{x:3,y:5,z:2},{x:8,y:3,z:6}];
```

which holds 3 vertices.

What I want to do is to sort it from higher y coordinate.

I can be defined like this

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return b.y-a.y});
```

But I should do this for about 10,000 times at once,and repeat it with `requestAnimationFrame(func);`.
I think there would be faster way.
Does anyone know how to make this faster?

Comment: There’s probably a way to avoid sorting your array on *every* animation frame, but we’d need more context (and code) to help.

Comment: `b.y - a.y` is not in general a good idea for comparison, because it can lead to wrong answers. To see why, read https://blog.mischel.com/2016/11/21/subtraction-is-not-the-same-as-comparison/

Comment: @Jim Mischel Thank you for the reply! But I dont need to calculate that huge number.

Comment: Be that as it may, using subtraction in place of real comparison is a very bad habit to get into. One day you will write that and it'll work fine. Then, six months or six years later, your program starts returning weird results because conditions changed: your program is being presented very large numbers. I'll tell you from experience that this bug is extremely hard to track down, and you'll look like a fool when you have to explain to your coworkers and your boss.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Is comparison faster than subtraction?

Comment: No, comparison is not faster than subtraction. At least, not in Javascript. But a proper comparison is *correct* 100% of the time. That seems a bit more important to me. And, honestly, if your code is so dependent on the few microseconds' difference between subtraction and proper comparison, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Ok,I got it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should call the built-in sort function.  It's probably written in a language that's faster than JavaScript and should be well-optimized.

Even for small arrays, you probably can't do better by writing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it before but.. Maybe it was too hard for my exynos..